How to compile a DLL via mingw32-gcc with `dllimport` and `dllexport`
You have got C++ code is supposed to compile on Windows and on Linux. I am using mingw32 on Windows and GCC on Linux.
The analog of Linux's shared objects on Windows are DLLs.
According to the GCC documentation, compiling some DLL on Windows is generally done via __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport).
How can I generate an DLL but without cluttering my code with these attributes? For example, are there any options to automatically and implicitly declare all non-inline defined functions as dllexport and all imported functions as dllimport?

You normally use a macro that is empty on linux or __declspec(dllexport) when building the dll on windows or __declspec(dllimport) when using the dll on windows. https://bumbershootsoft.wordpress.com/2019/04/07/working-with-dlls-on-windows-mac-and-linux/

@drescherjm Yes, but I specifically want to avoid the use of such macros.

People parse the objdump and produce a .def file. In practice you just make a MYDLL_API that uses compiler definitions to resolve to declspec export or import depending on what project it is in.
